# How to implement a simple chat option for server-client based game (blender/BGE)

Tags: python

I want 2 players to be able to chat with eachother. I have a running server-client game, but I'm kind of stuck on this one.

Since there are only outdated videos this is an example I need:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTPsNYLg2oY

It's just a very simple chat method, but I don't know how to integrate my Python code into Blender.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Nick I have a server-client chatroom, but that only works on commandline. I just don't know how to use this within blender. I have a server and client running in blender which handles player movement etc(including sockets).

Comment: Sorry I don't really have experience in making games in blender, also i'd recommend you not to do so, there are much better and more flexible platforms out there to use, where you can achieve better results, faster, with bigger community, less problems, without burning your brain basically. Like Unreal Engine or Unity

Comment: @Nick I know mate, but for some f*cking reason our school decided to give us a project which was based around creating a game in Blender. Don't ask me why, I absolutely disgust this project. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: You could try protesting, but ok thats out of forum topic. Your welcome, you may expect help from professional blender game developers(such dont exist actly) on this site though.